# How to get jQuery Validation Engine and prettyCheckboxes working together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, checkbox, drop-down-menu, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using jQuery Validation Engine and prettyCheckboxes jQuery plugins for my WordPress site.

Initially JVE integrates compatibilty with a plugin that styles `<select>`'s (jQuery selectBox) and I've been trying to do the same with an `<input type="checkbox">` replacement plugin, prettyCheckboxes.

You have to add `prettySelect : true` as an option within the plugin initialisation, so I added a `prettyCheckboxes : true` to the plugin, which you can see in the gist below on lines `164`, `330`, `495`, `693` and `1944` within the modified plugin.

As well as this you have to do some ID/class jiggery to make sure that IDs aren't repeated and classes aren't added where they shouldn't be. I've also had to add in the "checked" attribute to the hidden `<input type="checkbox">` so the JVE plugin picks up that it's changed.

It works only up to the point where I can get an error message to display, but it's wrong. Basically when you click on a checkbox, it registers the message to display and when you uncheck the message disappears; it's vice versa. But when you click on other checkboxes once you've unclicked the first clicked, it doesn't work at all **unless you do it in the order you clicked initially**. It's really weird.

So my question is, **how can I get prettyCheckboxes to work with JVE correctly**? Obviously I've modified it incorrectly but I'm just not sure where or how to get it to work as intended.

Modified jQuery Validation Engine, prettyCheckboxes, custom HTML and scripts: https://gist.github.com/0349d8c92039fc8c6009
(sorry I can't post more than two hyperlinks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason some of my code was interfering with the plugin:

```
$('.custom-tick').click(function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
            $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]')
                .attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]')
                .attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

I removed it and the checkboxes are activating the validation correctly.